# How to get text-overflow:ellipsis to work in a table?

Tags: html, css

[code pen](http://codepen.io/mnbayazit/pen/hHdri)

### css

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 14.285714286%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
th {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
td {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px;
}
.event-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.event-list li {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
span.day {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.other-month .day {
    color: #888;
}
td.other-month {
    background-color: #eee;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

### html

```
<td class="day-cell current-month"><span class="day">2</span><ul class="event-list"><li>1-4 FM - Fishing</li></ul></td>
```

I've set the width of each of the table cells to 14.28% but the `<li>`s push the table cells out even though I have `overflow:hidden` on them. I don't want the list-items to stretch the cells; I want them to show an ellipsis if the line is to long. Is that possible?

Comment: I do see ellipses (http://i.imgur.com/p6LDgDp.jpg) or something else is expected?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes. All the table cells should have the same width. Those ellipses only appear if they go under the date number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `table-layout: fixed;` to `table`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Zx5/

**Explanation:** This will force the table cells to have the specified width of `14.285714286%;` *forcefully*, hence preventing the table cells to grow in width with the content, and resulting in the ellipsis to occur in your desired width.

Comment: Perfect!  Didn't know about that property.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding text-overflow: ellipsis;?

I have this working with bootstrap at [THIS DEMO LINK](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/cover.html)

It uses the following CSS

```
.setWidth {
 max-width: 80px;
 }

.concat>div {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: inherit;
}
```

For this HTML

```
<td class="setWidth concat"><div>Some text for table cell here</div></td>
```

Comment: Did you even look at the CSS?